# The code outputs a number instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, this, lexical-scope

According to my understanding, the code below should output undefined when I call `hi()` but instead it logs a number. I'm using chrome. Can somebody elaborate why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

**Screen shot of Code:**

[image]

```js
const obj = {
  name: "abc",
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

obj.sayHi();
let hi = obj.sayHi;
hi();
```

Comment: This is the classic problem everyone faces while learning js. This problem arises due to the context of `this` for js `function` syntax. Try googling js normal function vs arrow functions.

Comment: Can't reproduct this, it works for me. Value is undefined as it should be

Comment: You're not using strict mode, so `this.name` is `window.name` which is not undefined if you run it in a browser window. If you add `"use strict";` as the first line of your function, you will get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`, since `this` is `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer. The window object already had a variable ```name``` that's why it was outputting that number. But I still don't understand one thing. Usually the code inside chrome runs in strict mode, while learning the about ```this```, I used the console to confirm this. And if that was the case, ```this``` should not be pointing to global object but undefined instead.

Comment: @aaKhan JavaScript is not in strict mode unless you `"use strict"` or the code is part of a class.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `obj.sayHi()`, `this` refers to `obj`.

When you call `hi()`, `this` refers to the `window` object.

If you want `this` to be `undefined`, you'll need to use `"use strict";`.

If you want `this` to be `obj`, you can `bind` the function to `obj`.

#### Demo

```js
"use strict"

const obj = {
  name: "abc",
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

obj.sayHi();

let hi1 = obj.sayHi;
hi1();


let hi2 = obj.sayHi.bind(obj);
hi2();
```